# Apscheduler are just running once when I set daily

Tags: python, apscheduler

I need a daily function trigger with APSscheduler setting. However, APS scheduler just can trigger once. As I showed with my code, I set 21:00 trigger every day, but it can only trigger with the first 21:00.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler

# Running Timer
scheduler = BackgroundScheduler(timezone='asia/taipei')


def push_today():
    # Running with my triggered code

def entry_point(upgrade_hint):    
    scheduler.add_job(push_today, 'cron', year='*', month='*', day="*", hour=21, minute=0, second=0)
    scheduler.start()

    # Flask app
    entry.app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    entry_point()
```

Thanks

**[20231023 - Update]**
I observed that 'Run time of job XXX was missed by 0:00:03.054418' on my app. It seems apscheduler has a mechanism that ignore cron job when missing my configured time.

I'll add `misfire_grace_time`, `coalesce`, and `max_instances` to test again.

Comment: Have you followed the [troubleshooting instructions](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/3.x/userguide.html#troubleshooting) from the documentation?

Comment: I'll try it, and report if I get some info.

Thanks

Comment: Update observation on the above 20231023 tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the library does not do the action because of it miss the setting time. To avoid this, setting misfire_grace_time to allow the missing time region.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).